# how to make multiple line string to single line string?

Tags: java, java-11

I have below string

```
String str="select * from m_menus;

select * from m_roles";
```

I want above string in one line
like

```
String str="select * from m_menus;select * from m_roles";
```

I have tried

```
str1=str.replace("[\r\n]+", " ");
```

and also

```
str1=str.replace("\n"," ");
```

Both are not working.

Comment: Stupid question.. but why don't you just do this in the first place?: `String str="select * from m_menus;select * from m_roles";`  Is it really the string that's the problem or are you passing it to a SQL engine and getting results you're not happy with.

Comment: @forsvarir Probably he is getting string in that manner from user input?

Comment: I am taking string as input from user

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to use regex, you should use the `String.replaceAll()` method.

Comment: Doesn't it? He's using what looks like a regex expression in a method that makes no claim to understand such.

Answer (score 21):

Use [`String.replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) instead.

```
str1=str.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ");
```

Answer (score 11):

No regular expressions and operating system independent:

```
str1.replaceAll(System.lineSeparator(), " ");
```

Windows uses \r\n as a line breaker, while *nix systems use only \n.

Answer (score 3):

Why don't you use `str.replaceAll("\r\n", " ")` ?

Should work and replace all occurences.

Answer (score 1):

**Using Java 11 lines()**

Java 11 has added new method `String::lines`, `lines` method uses specialized `Spliterator` to lazily provide lines from the source string

```
yourMultilineString.lines().collect(Collectors.joining(";"));
```

**Note** The string uses Windows’ `\r\n` and even though I’m on Linux, lines() still splits it. That’s because regardless of the operating system, **the method treats \r, \n, and \r\n as line terminators and splits there** – even if they are mixed in the same string.

Answer (score 0):

```
String actualTooltip_3 = string.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ");
```

**/////////--------how to make multiple line string to single line string?--------////////**
///string - value having multi lines

///actualTooltip_3 - Value shown in a single line

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k6GAc.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hNrIl.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

```
str1=str.replaceAll("[\r\n]+", " ");
```

Comment: try to highlight the keywords and be clear with the format it will help to reach out your answer for others and do write and explain your answer